# Possible to run Dropbox within Nitrous.IO?

Tags: dropbox, nitrousio

Nitrous.IO looks incredible. I'd love to use it with my students. However, we need the ability to have files locally accessible too. If we could run Dropbox on each Nitrous.IO box, that would be ideal. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Nitrous.IO has a Mac OS X application that handles local file syncing. So Mac users can utilize TextMate, SublimeText, etc... to edit their code and run it in the cloud.  The Mac App is free to download:

https://www.nitrous.io/mac

For those not on Macs, you could use FTP or SCP, but I realize that might not be ideal:

http://help.nitrous.io/faq-adding-project/

Dropbox integration is on the product roadmap.  Stay tuned to @nitrousio on twitter for updates.

Comment: The mac application wouldn't work for us anyway I think. We need all the students' files synced to a computer. With dropbox, each student shares their folder with us. FTP/SCP doesn't deal with synchronization.

Comment: I assume you're with Nitrous.IO? Dropbox integration would be phenomenal. Any idea when that can be expected.

Comment: It's on our product roadmap, you can follow @nitrousio on twitter as we'll definitely announce it there.

Comment: @ajhit406 LMK if I can help with Dropbox integration!

Comment: @Dan - I'm using Dropbox' linux command line client with Nitrous.IO. Unfortunately it keeps unlinking computers from Dropbox. We then have to relink them. A huge pain. I've written Dropbox customer support (eventually I get an apology email that Dropbox is too busy to answer) and created Dropbox forum posts, I can't figure out why the Dropbox clients keep getting unlinked. Is the Dropbox linux command line client supported?

Comment: try API Support on the developer site and tell them I sent you. Need to learn more about the use case.

Comment: I would like to be able to install the linux command line clinet on nitrous as well...any update @ajhit406

Answer (score 2):

There's a sync integration for windows, very much like Dropbox, using copy.com: Instructions here: https://coderwall.com/p/ixfokg.

Comment: This looks very interesting. I'd have to write a script to periodically check if the `CopyConsole` program is active as Nitrous.IO will shut down your VM if inactive. I love Dropbox and I'd have to investigate copy.com, but this may be our solution at least for now!

Answer (score 1):

So far dropbox has been running perfect! I'd love to know if there's any issue with running it this way... I simply ran:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
nohup ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Unfortunately Dropbox has proven to be a real problem for us because it keeps unlinking the Nitrous.IO boxes :(. We have to kill the `dropbox` process, run it again in the foreground, get the re-link URL, visit it while logged into Dropbox, quit the `dropbox` process and run it again in the background. Doesn't seem too difficult, but when working with students, having them do this every other day and remember their Dropbox credentials... it's a major problem.